# Show formatted decimal rounding to specific amount of digits

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, number-formatting

I'm working with .net core, and I having some issues formatting one number.

I have a decimal like this

```
decimal d = 362250;
```

And i want to show it rounded to 4 digits

> ```
> 3623
> ```

I was reading both [Decimal.ToString formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) and [custom number formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but i wans't be able to do it

I try :

```
Console.WriteLine($"{d:####}"); //show 362250
Console.WriteLine($"{d:####,}"); //show 362
```

How can i achieve that?

I know its so simple, but I fighting with it for 2 hours!

Comment: That's not rounded, though, that's a fundamentally different number -- which is why mere formatting won't do it and you'll have to apply some calculation, though it's not clear what. What should `108` become? How about `123456789`?

Comment: @Juan - what about  Math.Ceiling(d / 100) ?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hi, ty! `108` should become `108`, and `123456789` `1233`

Comment: That's a really weird way of treating the numbers since you erase the magnitude. Even then, shouldn't `123456789` become either `1235` (rounding `1234.5`)? Otherwise it's not clear why `362250`  would become `3623`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You're right, it should be `1235` i miss up, i want to show the numbers like exel do when you show less digits in the cell, do you know what i mean?

Comment: Not really, no -- my Excel refuses to eliminate significant digits. `123456789` will never shrink, no matter how few digits I ask for. At most it will reduce the number to `1.235E+08` in scientific notation, which maintains the magnitude (that would be `#.###E+00` as a C# format string, which reduces `108` to `1.08E+02`).

Comment: No idea why are you trying this, but
`var d=362250; var sig=4; return Math.Round(d/Math.Pow(10,(Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(d)))-sig)))` d=number, sig=significant portion

Comment: @MikeMakarov: be careful in that all those calculations happen on `double`s; `Math` does not have separate support for `decimal`. This matters because, in principle, decimal rounding on `decimal`s is always possible to do precisely, unlike for `double`s, so the outcomes can differ.

Comment: @JeroenMostert he's cutting a value UP to x digits :) I do understand your concern, and agree in theory there can be a value that would trigger that Double epsilon noise, but for hist scenario, I'd say, i't ultimately not going to make things worse...